# Copying a template header to multiple existing files

Tags: linux, command-line, cat, tcsh

I have a bunch of *.csv files that use headers. Right now the files have headers and the same number of lines of data. I need to erase the data in these files, so I figured I could just overwrite the header into the files. I have file `A` set up properly with the header. How can I `cat` `A` into all the other csv files?

Alternatively, how could I delete the last X number of lines from the files? The path for the files is `*/*.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cat the header into each of the files. I am assuming that `A` is a file since you mentioned `cat`. If so, you can just copy:

   ```
   for file in */*.csv; do cp A "$file"; done
   ```

   If `A` is a variable, do

   ```
   for file in */*.csv; do echo "A" > "$file"; done
   ```

   Alternatively, if all you need is the first line, you can cat that into each file. That way, it will also work for different headers:

   ```
   for file in */*.csv; do head -n "$file" > /tmp/foo && 
     mv /tmp/foo "$file"; 
   done
   ```
2. There are *many* ways to delete the last X number of lines from the files. Here are three:

   - [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head), change X to however many lines you want to keep:

     ```
     for file in */*.csv; do
       head -n X $file > /tmp/foo && mv /tmp/foo "$file"; 
     done
     ```
   - `awk`, change the `123` to however many lines you want to keep:

     ```
     for file in */*.csv; do
       awk 'NR<=123' "$file" > /tmp/foo && mv /tmp/foo "$file"; 
     done
     ```
   - `perl`, change the `123` to however many lines you want to keep:

     ```
     for file in */*.csv; do
       perl -ne "next if $.>123;print' "$file" > /tmp/foo && 
       mv /tmp/foo "$file"; 
     done
     ```

Comment: To delete the last X lines I found it easiest to use `sed` where `<N>` is the first line you want to delete and `$` is used to specify the last line: `sed -i '<N>,$d'`. For example, to delete from the 2nd line to the end: `sed -i '2,$d'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed and some pipe creativity to convert a list of files (or anything) into a list of commands.

This is a test, it will just output the commands for you to see what is going to happen:

```
$ ls *.cvs | sed "s/.*/cat headerfile.cvs > &/"
```

If you like it, do the same and pipe it to your favorite shell:

```
$ ls *.cvs | sed "s/.*/cat headerfile.cvs > &/" | bash
```

Or for a recursive solution you can use find:

```
find . -name \*.cvs | sed "s/.*/cat headerfile.cvs > &/" | bash
```